# Flatten out a structure in mongo Projection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

As part of aggregate pipeline and then using the project operator I have data in the following format

```
[
      {
         "Id": "id1",
         "Title": "title1",
         "Users": [
            {
               "Id": "User1",
               "Title": "User 1 title",
               "UserDetail": {
                  "Address": "Address1",
                  "Email": " Email1"
               }
            },
            {
               "Id": "User2",
               "Title": "User 2 title",
               "UserDetail": {
                  "Address": "Address2",
                  "Email": " Email2"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
```

I want the structure to be in the format something like this

```
[
   {
      "Id": "id1",
      "Title": "title1",
      "Users": [
         {
            "Id": "User1",
            "Title": "User 1 title",
            "UserAddress": "Address1",
            "UserEmail": " Email1"
         },
         {
            "Id": "User2",
            "Title": "User 2 title",
            "UserAddress": "Address2",
            "UserEmail": " Email2"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I am trying to do it with AddFields and map operator to extract from userDetails something like this

```
{
   "$addFields": {
      "UserAddress": {
    $map: {
         input: "$Users.UserDetails",
         as: "userdetails",
         in: "$$userdetails.Address"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I do not see any results as part of the map operation. Could you guys tell me what i am doing wrong here and how to fix it ? thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to do this.  Here's one way.

[comments in the code]

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "Users": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$Users",
          "as": "user",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              { // everything except UserDetail
                "$arrayToObject": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": {
                      // create key(k)/value(v) pairs
                      "$objectToArray": "$$user"
                    },
                    "as": "kv",
                    "cond": { // keep everything except UserDetail
                      "$ne": ["$$kv.k", "UserDetail"]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              { //New fields
                "UserAddress": "$$user.UserDetail.Address",
                "UserEmail": "$$user.UserDetail.Email"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xjkABr8S4f2).